# No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, transactions

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://uy-agent009.soutcom.ru:5432/user
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=mySecretPassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=50
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50

spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=DEBUG
```

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.agent.console", "com.agent.integrations.spring"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.agent.console")
public class AdminConsoleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        emFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        emFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.agent.console");
        return emFactory;
    }
}
```

I use PagingAndSortingRepository. When I start the main class and try to run the Get method in the controller using Postman, I get a message: **"NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!"**

I tried to solve the problem by adding the following code:

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
```

But then there is another exception:

**"CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections"**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see where you define the datasource to be used

Comment: it's define in application.properties. But I do not know how to link it to other settings in application.properties

Comment: In your application.propertis you set the property to use. You should define a datasource and use it too; i'm missing the em.setDatasource instruction